# Xcode simulator - Navigation bar is missing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar, xcode7

I don't know why but my navigation bar is missing from my ios simulation.

Anybody know where might be the problem?

Yes I have "Shows Navigation bar" and I don't have any warnings.

I wanted to try "Update frames" but I don't have this option available.

I am using Xcode 7.3 and Swift.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: did you change uinavigationbar's transparent?

Comment: show us code what r u doing in code and is it show on real device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve by **embedding** a **navigation controller**:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I didn't have app entry point on navigator controller but on my view scene. I didn't know it.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said in the comments without showing some code or screenshot of IB it's hard to find out where the problem is... But here's some things to checkout.

Are you sure your view controller is embedded in a `UINavigationController`?

If you are using Storyboards you should have something like this:

[image]

In code instead you might have set the `window.rootViewController` property in the `AppDelegate` to the content view controller rather than the navigation controller which is supposed to contain it.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend how to embedding navigation controller but you can try to embedding navigation controller following below way and than run application and check in simulator :  Go to Editor in xcode -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: the navigation bar was showing on the root view in Storyboard, but when running the Simulator - there was no navigation bar at the top of the views. This solved it:

Navigation Controller > Navigation Bar > UNCHECK Translucent (it is checked by default). This did two things:

1. My Navigation Bar shows on all subsequent views.
2. The topmost subview on subsequent views is now at Y=0, and not Y=64.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There are **two possibilities**.

1) May be you didn't Embeded navigationcontroller before your viewcontroller. so, add Navigation controller with go to

**Editor -> Embededin -> Navigation controller**.

[image]

[image]

2) If you have add navigation controller but May be you have set **NONE** as **topbar** of **Viewcontroller**.

[image]

Comment: For 2) - if you change some parameters in Simulated Metrics - are you sure that it would affect app on device or simulator?

Comment: No simulated metrics is what it says. Simulated. It's just for designing.

Comment: @smileBot Can you please explain ?

Comment: @BadalShah Simulated metrics has nothing to do with what happens when the app is run. It is just there for designing. This is a common mistake.